# Is it wise to stay with locals in Estonia, Lithuania and/or Latvia?

Tags: estonia, latvia, lithuania, baltic-region

I'm planning on going to Estonia (alternatively Lithuania and/or Latvia) and I'd like to experience a normal Tallinn/Riga/Vilnius life. I'm referring to the small thing, such as (but of course not limited to) eating a breakfast. If I stay at a hotel, I know that I'll have some bacon, eggs and coffee with a croissant. As I do at **every** hotel.

So this time, my plan is to see the real way of the locals.

Hence, I have two questions.

1. Is it wise to do that in Estonia to begin with or should I have consideration against it?
2. If it is, where can I get in touch with locals willing to host me (I'm willing to pay and I have no special requirements)?

Comment: Couchsurfing, or perhaps Airbnb, are good bets. Look for hostels if you want to meet other travelers.

Comment: You mean something like a Bed&Breakfast? I think simple “Pension”/B&B which might provide a less standardised experience than large hotels are common in these countries. Otherwise, it might be a big step for you but have you heard about couch surfing?

Comment: @Relaxed B&B is still too much hotel'ish for this idea. I wish to stay in actual home of a normal person. Couch surfing might be an idea - I just want to know if it's recommended to stay clear of that. I've heard stories about sex orgies being organized that way (not sure how much truth there is to that, of course) and I strongly prefer not to wake up with someone's genitalia to my face (one of my very few requirements). Any areas to avoid when being hosted?

Comment: @Moriarty Air B&B didn't really worked out for me. I tried it twice - once, the guy lied, the second time, the couple wasn't home. Less pleasant experience. Couch surfing is an idea but I'm not sure how well it works in Baltics. I can cynically assume that there's always someone using a great idea in a wrong way. Have you tried CS'ing there?

Comment: @KonradViltersten Nope, my personal preference is to stay in hostels or small owner-operated B&Bs. If you find accommodation that is operated as a business (rather than just some dude who occasionally lets foreigners rent a spare room or sleep on his couch), you're much less likely to have your plans ruined by unreliable hosts. *If you really want to stay with and be entertained by the locals, be prepared for if things don't work out*.

Comment: From the question and comments, it sounds like you want all the immersion of being someone's house guest, while also getting the customer service and convenience of being a hotel guest. That's not possible. If you're a house guest, fitting into someone else's life, you *will* need to act like a house guest, and be prepared to compromise, fit in with their schedule, etc etc. *(p.s. being put off couch surfing because <0.1% of people use it for orgies is like never staying in hotels because <0.1% of hotels are fronts for brothels. Just don't sign up to attend an orgy)*

Comment: @user568458 Naa, it seems my intention got lost. I don't expect hotel treatment. In fact, helping to clean the apartment for instance and go shop for groceries would be very welcome part of the experience. As for the orgy part, I was curious if anyone of those who's done couch surfing, especially in the Batlics, can give me an idea of how abused (or well used) it usually is.

Comment: I'm confused about this orgy concern - surely it would have to (knowingly) involve the couchsurfer to work...

Comment: @CMaster Never been to an orgy (a state which I'm very satisfied with) so I can only speculate. In the story I've been told (not claiming it's true to any extent), the host was doing things **onto** the guest (probably hoping that they'd start participating once the option's been so explicitly established or perhaps merely enjoying taking advantage of the circumstances). But if I hear of any orgies, I'll make sure to let you know. You can then investigate and provide feed-back, hihihi.

Comment: @CMaster On a more serious note - what I meant is to ask if there are any inappropriate or criminal activities widely know to take place there. Be that an orgy or people going through my stuff putting drugs in a hidden compartment of my bag. Better ask then to "*pee the fence*", if you're familiar with the expression. I'm just trying to be cautious.

Comment: @Moriarty I think your first comment satisfies the requirements of an answer? (Perhaps with slightly more explanation)

Comment: @davidvc I do agree. The answer being not that much *Air B&B* and CouchSurfin* but rather that there's no special comments nor examples on well-known wrong-doings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Airbnb](http://airbnb.com/) and [Couchsurfing](http://couchsurfing.com/) are two services often used to find accommodation hosted by locals.

Airbnb accommodation is paid and varies from mansions to hay bales. By specifying "Shared room" or "Private room" in your search, you can often find rooms, mattresses, etc. in apartments or houses occupied by locals. The degree of interaction with your host depends on the specific stay; reading descriptions and reviews will help you find the experience you want.

Couchsurfing is free of charge, but guests are expected to contribute a reasonable amount in terms of conversation, chores, maybe a gift, etc (leave your accommodation nicer than you found it).

You can probably find the homestay experience you're looking for on either site, the difference being that, because of Airbnb's cost, its hosts will generally expect slightly less in terms of nonmonetary contribution from guests (although gifts, conversation, and helping with chores are certainly welcome).

On the whole, accommodation from either site will be safe and pleasant; as with any part of the sharing economy, reviews and ratings provide information you can use to increase your chances of a positive experience.